# jQuery autocomplete: How to separate the url of the javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

For a website, I will have a lot of auto complete fields on differents pages.

They works exactly the same on all pages, except they must not call the same url.

I was wondering if there is a possibility to mention the url on the `<input>` which is going to be an autocomplete field? The goal is to have one js code for many html codes

I tried something, but it doesn't seems to works:
Html:

```
<input type="field" name="search" class="autocomplete" value="Search" url="smalltest/otherTest/..." />
```

And the JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: $(this).attr("url")
    }); });
```

I got exception in jquery lib.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the url attribute to `data-url` then in your .autocomplete do this:

`source: $(this).data("url")`